# How can I find all the ui text components in the hierarchy and then to disable/enable them?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For now I created array of Text and then dragging in the editor one by one to the inspector to the array.
The problem is that some Text ui are childs or childs of childs and it's not easy to find them all one by one.

How can I loop over the hierarchy or find all the text ui and then to disable/enable them ?

I need it for my game pause/resume.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text[] uiTexts;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                DisableEnableUiTexts(false);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DisableEnableUiTexts(bool uiTextEnabled)
    {
        if (uiTexts.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Text ui in uiTexts)
            {
                if (uiTextEnabled)
                {
                    ui.GetComponent<Text>().enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    ui.GetComponent<Text>().enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update :

I tried this :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [ContextMenuItem("Fetch", nameof(FetchAllTexts))]
    public Text[] uiTexts;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                DisableEnableUiTexts(false);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void FetchAllTexts()
    {
        var tmp = new List<Text>();
        for (var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++)
        {
            foreach (var root in SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).GetRootGameObjects())
            {
                tmp.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(true));
            }
        }
        Text[] texts = tmp.ToArray();

        uiTexts = texts;
    }

    private void DisableEnableUiTexts(bool uiTextEnabled)
    {
        if (uiTexts.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Text ui in uiTexts)
            {
                ui.enabled = uiTextEnabled;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't see the "Fetch" ContextMenuItem anywhere. Tried right click on the object in hierarchy where the script is attached to tried in the Assets tried in the editor menu/s it's not there.

Comment: FindObjectsOfType<Text>() will return all the active text objects in the scene as Text [].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said either use [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html)

```
Text[] texts = FindObjectsOfType<Text>();
```

will return all **active** and **enabled** instances of `Text`.

---

However to get also disabled/inactive ones you can use

```
var tmp = new List<Text>();
for(var i = 0; i < SceneManager.sceneCount; i++)
{
    foreach(var root in SceneManager.GetSceneAt(i).GetRootGameObjects)
    {
        tmp.AddRange(root.GetComponentsInChildren<Text>(true));
    }
}
Text[] texts = tmp.ToArray();
```

which iterates over all loaded scenes and fetches **ALL** instances also currently inactive or disabled ones.

See

- [`SceneManager.sceneCount`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager-sceneCount.html)
- [`SceneManager.GetSceneAt`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetSceneAt.html)
- [`Scene.GetRootGameObjects`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.GetRootGameObjects.html)
- [`GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponentsInChildren.html)

---

Then you can e.g. fetch this **once** either in `Start` or even earlier via the Inspector itself so you don't have to do it at every app start using [`[ContextMenuItem]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ContextMenuItemAttribute.html).

```
public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    [ContextMenuItem("Fetch", nameof(FetchAllTexts)]
    public Text[] uiTexts;

    private void FetchAllTexts()
    {
        uiTexts = // One of the methods shown above
    }

    ...
}
```

Why is this a good thing? As said this way you don't have to do it every time in `Start` and thus delaying the app start until it is done.

Instead you store all the references already via the Inspector in a SerializeField so when your app starts, this component already "knows" these references and you don't have to get them first.

Simply right click on the `uiTexts` field in the Inspector and hit `Fetch`

---

Then in general you would simply write

```
private void DisableEnableUiTexts(bool uiTextEnabled)
{
    foreach (Text ui in uiTexts)
    {
        ui.enabled = uiTextEnabled;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see the "Fetch" ContextMenuItem anywhere. Tried right click on the object in hierarchy where the script is attached to tried in the Assets tried in the editor menu/s it's not there.

Comment: Right click on the field `uiTexts` in the Inspector ;)

Comment: I had to make one empty field of the array in the inspector of the uiTexts and then right click on that empty field give the Fetch option. Just on the Ui Texts won't work. Anyway working great thanks,

Comment: Oh sorry .. forgot about that Unity hickup for array fields in the Inspector ^^ Alternatively you can also tag the methods itself `[ContextMenu("Fetch Texts")]` and open the context menu of the Component in the Inspector and find it there ;) If this answers your question feel free to accept the answer